# Alternative to .FromSql for empty stored procedure results

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using a stored procedure to return data from SQL Server. However, I'm using `FETCH NEXT` to get the data, which means if no data is returned I get this error:

> The number of rows provided for a FETCH clause must be greater then zero.

I therefore need to wrap the `SELECT` statement in an `IF` statement, so the `SELECT` is only called if data will be returned:

```
IF @TotalCount > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT
    ...
    OFFSET @SkipResults ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END
```

I'm then using this command to get the data back as a DbSet:

```
var data = await dbContext.MyDataSet.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE myProcedure @Param1, @Param2", param1, param2).ToListAsync();
```

where the `dbContext.MyDataSet` is defined as:

```
DbSet<MyDataModel> MyDataSet { get; set; }
```

and `MyDataModel` has these properties:

```cs
public class MyDataModel 
{
    public int CompletedPercentage { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is when `@TotalCount` is 0 in the stored procedure, no data is returned from the stored procedure.

The code then throws an exception:

> The required column 'CompletedPercentage' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

Is there an alternative way of using a stored procedure to populate my `DbSet<MyDataModel> MyDataSet` property, that works both when data is returned, or not returned?

Comment: Does `@TotalCount` reflect the number of rows in the `SELECT` query results? In that case, you  could remove the IF condition. The query would return an empty result with  schema.

Comment: Cannot repro your `FETCH` error, see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f345485a82892aa24fb77cfd6d282892 AFAIK the error `The number of rows provided for a FETCH clause must be greater then zero.` will only be returned if you actually provide 0 to it, not if the resultset it operates on has not enough rows. Perhaps you just need a conditional on the `@PageSize` value

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the advice, you've pointed my brain in the right direction.

I've removed the `IF` statement and moved the check into the WHERE clause, as I'm hoping this will mean the complex `SELECT` statement won't execute if `@TotalCount = 0`

```sql
SELECT
...
WHERE
    @TotalCount > 0
OFFSET @SkipResults ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

I also had some logic in the stored procedure that I didn't include in the question...

```sql
IF @PageSize < 1
    SET @PageSize = @TotalCount
```

This has been changed to

```sql
IF @PageSize < 1
    SET @PageSize = CASE WHEN @TotalCount > 0 THEN @TotalCount ELSE 1 END
```

This fixes the error created by the `FETCH NEXT @PageSize` and I can now get the empty dataset back that I needed.